# Combine two single-channel TIFF stacks to a single multi-channel stack

Tags: image, command-line, imagemagick, tiff, imagemagick-convert

I've got two tiff stacks with time-lapse data corresponding to different channels acquired in a microscopy experiment. I'd like to merge them into a single stack with two channels. Both stacks are 16-bit greyscale.

When I use:

```
convert stack1.tiff stack2.tiff stack_merged.tiff
```

I get a single but concatenated file with two stacks one after another.

Links to [file 1](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/39860371/misc/Point01_C0.tiff) and [file 2](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/39860371/misc/Point01_C0.tiff).

Comment: Not sure about your term *"stack"*? Does a "stack" hold multiple images of, say, the Red channel at different times and another "stack" hold, say, the Green channel at the same times? Can you provide samples?

Comment: Does this give you what you want for the first image? `convert stack1.tiff[0] stack2.tiff[0] -channel RG -combine result.tif`

Comment: @MarkSetchell Yes, a stack contains multiple images recorded in one colour channel at different time points. I edited the question to include sample files. The suggested code produces 3 channels with one time point, which is not what I'm after.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Get index of last frame in TIFF image
last=$(convert stack1.tif -print "%[fx:n-1]" null:)

# Combine all frames
for i in `seq 0 $last`; do
   convert stack1.tif[$i] stack2.tif[$i] -combine miff:-
done | convert miff:- -compress lzw result.tif
```

Comment: Almost there, except it creates RGB channels. In there any way to restrict the conversion to 2 channels? convert -channel RG ... still produces all 3 channels, with the last one empty.

Comment: I have improved my original answer a little bit - more flexible in terms of number of images in stack and compressed output file, but am still trying to work out how to do a 2-channel image...

Comment: I see. This might be the mother of all my problems. I'll try playing with command-line tools from Bio-Formats then. Many thanks for your effort anyway!